# Aiming an arrow at a target

Tags: latex, tikz

I am writing a carom billard instruction manual in Latex. Illustrations are made with tikz. I need an arrow that always points from the cue ball in the direction to the object ball and is always the same lenght and at the same distance from the cue ball.

I have a solution drawing an arrow from cueball to object ball and shortening the line. This shortening however has to be done manually every time the distance between the balls changes, by trial and error.

Is there a way to automate this so I don't have to change the lenght by hand?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
    % Units definitions
        \def \tb {142} % width of table
        \def \tl {2*\tb} % lenght of table
        \def \d {\tb/4}; % diamonds
        \def \c {\tb/3}; % Cadre
        \def \bb {6.15}; % diameter of balls

        % Cueball coordinate
        \path (\c,\c) coordinate (B1);
        % Objectball coordinate
        \path (1.5*\bb,\c-\bb) coordinate (B2);

        % Arrow
        \draw [-Stealth, thick, shorten >=125, shorten <=30]
        (B1) --
        (B2);

        % Cueball
        \draw [fill=white] (B1)
        node[above left = 5]{\small Cueball} % Beschriftung
        circle (\bb/2);

        % Objectball
        \draw [fill=white] (B2)
        node[above left = 5]{\small Objectball} % Beschriftung
        circle (\bb/2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could draw the cue stick (you can add `draw,red` to the fake line and circles to see how this is constructed):

```
\def \distancetoball {6mm};
\def \sticklength {20mm};

% Define fake line that goes through the object ball and the cue ball
\path [name path=direction] ($(B1)!-\distancetoball-\sticklength!(B2)$) -- (B2);

% Define two fake circles around the cueball to place the cue stick
\path [name path=circle1] (B1) circle(\distancetoball);
\path [name path=circle2] (B1) circle(\distancetoball+\sticklength);

% Pick the intersection of the line with the two circles to be the two extremities of the cue stick
\path [name intersections={of=direction and circle1}];
\coordinate (tip) at (intersection-1);
\path [name intersections={of=direction and circle2}];
\coordinate (source) at (intersection-1);

% Draw the cue stick
\draw [-Stealth, thick] (source) -- (tip);
```

[image]